# user registration email alert to admin in moodle

Tags: php, email, registration, spam, moodle

I need to send a message to moodle admin, when new user is register on website. In basic moodle installation moodle send a user email with a validation mail, but not a admin or some other user to know when is new user register on website. I need that because, moodle website is public and anybody can register on this website. After few months, moodle have more then thousand new users, and maybe 10% is users that is a legal users. So I tray to find some solution to solve this problem and stop illegal users to use moodle website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, someone like I do need this. I solve this problem in two steps:

1. Using this [link](http://codeboxr.com/blogs/sending-customized-user-registration-email-alert-to-admin-in-moodle) I send a message to me, if new user register on website;
2. Using [recaptcha](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Email-based_self-registration) in moodle.

In a week ago I do that, and for now, I do reduce a illegal users on moodle. If user is not a robot, he will register, but I got a mail, and can delete or disable this user for login on sistem.
I Hope that someone searching for that and can use this :)